# Prove that if $S$ is a color class of a $k$-chromatic graph $G$,then there is a component $H$ of $G-S$ such that $\chi(H)=k-1$

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if $S$ is a color class resulting from a $k$-coloring of a $k$-chromatic graph $G$, where $k\geq 2$, then there is a component $H$ of $G-S$ such that $\chi(H)=k-1$

Here is what I understand.

Let $V_1, V_2, ..., V_k$ be the color class of $G$ since $G$ is $k$-chromatic. Let $S=V_i$ for $1\leq i \leq k$. In $G-S$ all vertices of the same color says $i$, are deleted, so $G-S$ has one less color than $G$.

Now $H$ is a component of $G-S$ meaning $H$ is a maximal subgraph of $G-S$, thus $\chi(H) \leq \chi(G-S)=k-1$

I want to show $\chi(H)=k-1$, then I need to show somehow that $\chi(H) \geq \chi(G-S)=k-1$. However, I can't see anyway to do that.

Comment: I thought that a component always meant a connected component...  That is, if the removal of $S$ does not separate the graph, then $G-S$ has exactly one component.  In this case, it shouldn't separate it into anymore than one component.  Right? I mean, recall the notation $k(G-S)$ which denotes the number of components in $G-S$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to only show that *there exists* a component $H$ with chromatic number $k-1$. Your approach is trying to show that *all* components have chromatic number $k-1$, but that is in fact not true: For example, consider $G$ on vertex set $a,b,c,d$ where $a,b,c$ form a triangle and $d$ is joined to $c$. Then take a proper $3$-colouring of $G$, and let $H=\{c\}$. Then $\{d\}$ is a component of $G-H$ with $\chi(\{d\})=1$.

Fortunately, existence easier to show: if *all* components of $G-H$ have chromatic number at most $k-2$, then certainly $\chi(G-H)\leq k-2$. So fix a $k-2$-colouring of $G-H$. Adding $H$ back to the graph and colouring all vertices in $H$ with a new colour gives a $k-1$-colouring of $G$.

Comment: I have a question, how do you know all component of $G-H$ have chromatic number at most $k-2$?

Comment: Its a proof by contradiction

Comment: There can only be 1 component!  If $G-S$ were disconnected, then there exists 2 color classes $C_m$ and $C_n$ with no edges between them.  Change the color of $C_m$ to the color of $C_n$ producing a k-1 coloring of G and hence a contradiction since $\chi (G)=k$.

Comment: @user3440448 that's not true

Comment: What isn't true?  My definition of component?  Or what?  Please elaborate.

Comment: @user3440448 its not true that $G-S$ has one component in general. See for example the graph described in my answer.

Comment: @Casteels Hmmmm.... good point.  I need to rethink some things.  Thanks for the counter example.